# Selecting elements in numpy array using regular expressions

Tags: regex, numpy, python

One may select elements in numpy arrays as follows

```
a = np.random.rand(100)
sel = a > 0.5 #select elements that are greater than 0.5
a[sel] = 0 #do something with the selection

b = np.array(list('abc abc abc'))
b[b==a] = 'A' #convert all the a's to A's
```

This property is used by the `np.where` function to retrive indices:

```
indices = np.where(a>0.9)
```

What I would like to do is to be able to use regular expressions in such element selection. For example, if I want to select elements from `b` above that match the `[Aab]` regexp, I need to write the following code:

```
regexp = '[Ab]'
selection = np.array([bool(re.search(regexp, element)) for element in b])
```

This looks too verbouse for me. Is there any shorter and more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You many have seen this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html , which would be useful if your starting point was a string or a file instead of an array.

Comment: Paul, thank you. Yes I saw this (this is the first google hit for "numpy regexp"), but this doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's some setup involved here, but unless numpy has some kind of direct support for regular expressions that I don't know about, then this is the most "numpytonic" solution.  It tries to make iteration over the array more efficient than standard python iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import re

r = re.compile('[Ab]')
vmatch = np.vectorize(lambda x:bool(r.match(x)))

A = np.array(list('abc abc abc'))
sel = vmatch(A)
```

Comment: from numpy docs: `The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.`

Comment: Link to documentation concerning the performance of [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html).